# Calling run reports in the google analytics add-on via google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-analytics, google-sheets

My question is regarding the [Google Analytics Spreadsheet Add-on](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on). Is there any way to access/call "Run reports" via Google apps script? Couldn't find it anywhere in the documentation.

Background info: I am trying to automate analytics reports with varying start and end times. I need to run the reports **a lot** and with a variety of values but can't seem to automate the actual running the report part.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question before, but google doesn't allow it yet.
The workaround is implement the query to Google Analytics inside your script.
But it is quite easy.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/reporting-apps-script#conclusion

My suggestion is that you can write all your report in a sheet, using the same format that you use in GA add-on, and since your script, read the data, query to GA, and generate a new sheet for each response.